# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'

Tags: android, build.gradle

I don't know why this error is there and I'm not able to solve it .
please give exact solution for this. I'm fed up of this error. I know this may dupliacate question but those solutions are not working for me. I can have debug apk but i can't generate signed apk.
while generating signed apk it gives me following exception:
**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.**

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: io/codetail/widget/RevealLinearLayout.class

here is my App Gradle:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.0'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.1.9'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.16'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.5l@aar'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
     compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile('com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile 'swarajsaaj:otpreader:1.0'
    compile('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.3.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-core:1.4.3'
    compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-commons:1.4.3'
    compile 'com.riontech.staggeredtextgridview:staggeredtextgridview:1.0.1'
    compile 'konifar:fab-transformation:1.0.0'
    compile project(':flickabledialog')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer to your question but why are you using three different different libraries for image loading ?  Picasso, Glide and Universal Image Loader in a single project ? and two different libraries for charts ?  MPAndroidChart and AChartEngine ? Why ? Just curious

Comment: @SomeshKumar probably newbie dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:

You have multiple

```
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'//remove this
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0' //remove this

compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6' // Two times
```

### NOTE

Lots of same dependencies present in your gradle section like above.Remove them .

Comment: and also remove one compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

Comment: A side question does Philjay contain the duplicate relevant class?

Comment: @humblerookie yes

Comment: Thank you so much .. this worked but facing another issue after that, background of my listview item changed to black from white though i have given its background color white.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i couldn't add that xml in comment so i added it as ans

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_class"
                    android:layout_weight="1.7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    android:textColor="@color/subtextcolor"
                    android:text="Class : 5A" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_date"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/datecolor"
                    android:text="Date : 12 Jan 2015" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:weightSum="4"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="Status"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/status"
                    android:textColor="@color/subtextcolor"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:text="5A"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/Present"
                    android:src="@drawable/p"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/subtextcolor"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:text="5A"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/absent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/subtextcolor"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:text="5A"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/t"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/subtextcolor"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:weightSum="4"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="Student"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/student"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/subtextcolor"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_present"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="53"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/datecolor"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_absent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/datecolor"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_total"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="50"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/datecolor"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="end"

                android:weightSum="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/edt_editattendance"
                    android:tint="@color/lightgreen"
                    android:src="@drawable/pencil_48"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add this in your question section

Comment: add `android:background="@color/white"` in First `LinearLayout` section .